# Select the same value multiple times from a dual listbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I use  `bootstrapDualListbox()`
to create an input that allows selecting the same value multiple times. I've been looking for a way to this, but didn't found. Assuming I have a list

```
<select multiple>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two</option>
<option value="3"> Three</option>
</select>
```

How to get an input that allows selecting this kind of multiple items: 1,1,2,3,3?

I've tried to find a way to use bootstrap dual listbox plugin, but I can only select one item one time. I'm expecting to select one item multiple times if I want to.

Comment: First, you'd need to allow multiple items to be selected with the keyword `multiple`. Next, is there a limit to how many times each item can be selected? Maybe when one is selected, you dynamically duplicate that item in JS so that it can be chosen again.

Comment: There will be no limit. The user will select the item the times they need. Is there a way to dynamically duplicate a selected item using bootstrap listbox?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to duplicate the option with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `multiple` attribute to your `<select>` so you can multi-select by holding
<kbd>CMD</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key

Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple)

```html
<select multiple>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two</option>
<option value="3"> Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've updated my question because I forgot I already had 'multiple' in my code. Of course, this does not allow me to select the same item multiple times.